# How to get N-th type from a tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdtuple

I want to make a template where I can input an index and it will give me the type at that index. I know I can do this with `decltype(std::get<N>(tup))` but I would like to implement this myself. For example, I would like to do this,

```
typename get<N, std::tuple<int, bool, std::string>>::type;
```

...and it will give me the type at position `N - 1` (because arrays indexed starting from 0). How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a class template and partial specializations to do what you want. (Note that `std::tuple_element` does almost the same like the other answer says):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <int N, typename... Ts>
struct get;

template <int N, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct get<N, std::tuple<T, Ts...>>
{
    using type = typename get<N - 1, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct get<0, std::tuple<T, Ts...>>
{
    using type = T;
};

int main()
{
    using var = std::tuple<int, bool, std::string>;
    using type = get<2, var>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<type, std::string>::value, ""); // works
}
```

Comment: @user1131467 it's just how I decided to do it

Answer (score 26):

That trait already exists, and it is called [`std::tuple_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element).

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b2a01561257902eef682c5344ccebc23-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc) that demonstrates its usage.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    using my_tuple = std::tuple<int, bool, char>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::tuple_element<0, my_tuple>::type, int>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::tuple_element<1, my_tuple>::type, bool>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::tuple_element<2, my_tuple>::type, char>::value, "!");
}
```

Comment: But I said I wanted to implement this myself. :)

Comment: Given that *"I know I can do this but I would like to implement this myself."*, this is not an answer but a comment (though a useful one, since the OP doesn't seem to know about `std::tuple_element`).

Comment: @user2030677: I'm sorry, I should have read the question's text better - I somehow skipped that part :)

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, I did not realize that when I wrote the answer (and I re-read the question a couple of times, my brain just skipped that part)

Comment: Might be the case that this doesn't fulfill all the constraints of the asker's question, but it's great for people coming in from a google search who don't care about implementing it themselves :)

Comment: C++14 also provides a `std::tuple_element_t<>` alias, which is short for `std::tuple_element<>::type`.