# Extract a type from a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++14

I am implementing a type extractor `extract_type<Class, nth-type>` for any templated class. An example usage is shown as follows:

```
template <int, short, float, double, char> class C;

extract_type<C, 0>::type => int
extract_type<C, 1>::type => short
extract_type<C, 2>::type => float
extract_type<C, 3>::type => double
extract_type<C, 4>::type => char
```

Here is my implementation.

```
// extract_type: recursive definition.
template <template <typename...> class C, size_t idx, typename T, typename... RestT> 
struct extract_type;

// extract_type: base
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename... RestT>
struct extract_type< C<RestT...>, 0, RestT... > { 
  using type = T;
};


// extract_type: recursive definition.
template <template <typename...> class C, size_t idx, typename T, typename... RestT>
struct extract_type : public extract_type< C<RestT...>, idx-1, RestT... > { 
};
```

However, the compiler complains about

> type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template class C, long unsigned int idx, class T, class ... RestT> struct OpenCluster::extract_type'
>   struct extract_type< void, 0, RestT...>

How can I get this resolved?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928669/how-to-get-n-th-type-from-a-tuple

Comment: `template <typename...> class C` is a template template parameter, which suddenly becomes a type template parameter in a spacialization. Moreover,  `<int, short, float, double, char>`, these are non-type template parameters, so `class C` can't even be matched against `template <typename...> class C`

Comment: Are you sure you want `extract_type<C, 1>`, and not `extract_type<C<int, short>, 1>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that (minimal, working example)?

```
#include<tuple>
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template<int, typename...>
struct extract_type;

template<int N, typename T, typename... O, template<typename...> typename U>
struct extract_type<N, U<T, O...>>: extract_type<N-1, U<O...>> { };

template<typename T, typename... O, template<typename...> typename U>
struct extract_type<0, U<T, O...>> { using type = T; };

int main() {
    using MyTuple = std::tuple<int, double, char>;
    // true
    std::cout << std::is_same<extract_type<1, MyTuple>::type, double>::value << std::endl;
    // false
    std::cout << std::is_same<extract_type<2, MyTuple>::type, double>::value << std::endl;
}
```

This one would be your code (fixed and working version) instead:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

// extract_type: recursive definition.
template <template <typename...> class C, size_t idx, typename T, typename... RestT> 
struct extract_type;

// extract_type: base
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename... RestT>
struct extract_type< C, 0, T, RestT... > { 
    using type = T;
};

// extract_type: recursive definition.
template <template <typename...> class C, size_t idx, typename T, typename... RestT>
struct extract_type : public extract_type< C, idx-1, RestT... > { };

int main() {
    // true
    std::cout << std::is_same<extract_type<std::tuple, 1, int, double, char>::type, double>::value << std::endl;
    // false
    std::cout << std::is_same<extract_type<std::tuple, 2, int, double, char>::type, double>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Pretty ugly, isn't it?

The problem is that you define it as if to pass the template class separated from its parameters, so that the former has no role within `extract_type`.
It means that you could have defined it as:

```
template <size_t idx, typename T, typename... RestT> 
struct extract_type;
```

So, it would have been used as:

```
extract_type<1, int, double, char>::type
```

With the same result: `double`.

Got the error in your example (apart the syntactic one, of course)?

Comment: Hi Skypjack. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Jes You used `typename... RestT` in your code. What does it mean? It's a [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), what else?

Comment: Yes. I understood. There is a mistake I made in declaring the template specialization.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation.

```
#include "iostream"

template<class ...Ts> struct C {};

template<int N, class ...Ts>
struct extract_type_impl;

template<class C, int N>
struct extract_type;

template<template<class ...> class C, class ...Ts, int N>
struct extract_type<C<Ts...>, N> {
  typedef typename extract_type_impl<N, Ts...>::type type;
};

template<int N, class T, class ...Ts>
struct extract_type_impl<N, T, Ts...> {
  typedef typename extract_type_impl<N - 1, Ts...>::type type;
};

template<class T, class ...Ts>
struct extract_type_impl<0, T, Ts...> {
  typedef T type;
};

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_same<extract_type<C<int, float, char, double>, 3>::type, double>::value, "");
  // static_assert(std::is_same<extract_type<C<int, float, char, double>, 3>::type, int>::value, "");
}
```

- Get the parameter lists of C
- Get n-th parameter

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/uyd0aV)

Comment: What against inheritance?

Comment: @skypjack : Some compilers (\*cough\* VC++ \*cough\*) give warnings when a type's inheritance tree exceeds a certain number of characters. Other than that, it's just personal preference AFAIK.