# get currently held typeid of std::variant (like boost::variant type())

Tags: c++, boost, typeid, std-variant

I've migrated from boost::variant to std::variant, and hit a snag.

I was using a nice function in boost 'type()' that lets you get the currently held typeid. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#id1752388-bb

How can this be achieved with std::variant?

I have an unordered map key'd on 'type_index', which holds some value 'std::function'. My variant, depending on the type, will determine what function I grab from the map to do some operation. (The code I have is far too large to post).

Any implementation ideas aside from writing a specific visitor for a particular std::variant? Maybe using the 'index()' function on the std::variant, to then index into the type list of the variant? Somewhat like this: [How to get N-th type from a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928669/how-to-get-n-th-type-from-a-tuple)

Comment: There is no such method, use index or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if instead indeed.

Comment: I saw 'get-if' but it requires you to have knowledge of the variant types. I was hoping for a generic solution.

Comment: I'm not sure getting the type info was any more generic than get_if or index.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
template<class V>
std::type_info const& var_type(V const& v){
  return std::visit( [](auto&&x)->decltype(auto){ return typeid(x); }, v );
}
```

Alternatively

```
template<class...Ts>
std::type_info const& var_type(std::variant<Ts...> const& v, std::optional<std::size_t> idx={}){
  if (!idx) idx=v.index();
  if(*idx==std::variant_npos) return typeid(void);
  const std::array<std::type_info const*, sizeof...(Ts)> infos[]={ &typeid(Ts)... };
  return *(infos[*idx]);
}
```

Which lets you ask about other indexes that are not active.

Comment: Nice, but what's with the `std::optional`? Lazy overloads?

Comment: @passer I thought "they can pass the index", then "but what if they don't want to".  Hence what I wrote.

Comment: Very nice, concise template solution!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the currently-selected type is known only at runtime, whereas "obtaining" a type must be done at compile-time. This is exactly why we have visitors — to hide away the unavoidable chain of `if` statements behind the `variant` implementation.

Instead of re-inventing that implementation, it would be best to perform your map dispatching from inside such a visitor.

Failing that, you will have to write your own chain of `if` statements, producing code that's similar to the use of a visitor, but probably slower and less maintainable!

It is true that you can't implement such a thing by reading `index()` then asking the variant to give you equivalent `typeid`, as you could with the Boost implementation. But I'm pretty sure that's deliberate, because (as I've suggested above) any code making use of that would be ill-advised. Of course, if you really wanted to, you could write a visitor to produce such a `typeid`! But then you still have to write conditional logic to deal with that value, when you could have just put the logic into the visitor in the first place.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote, but I selected the other answer as 'correct' since it has a code example for others to utilize with 'std::visit' that is generic (I gave an upvote for your answer)