# Is there any elegant way to combine asio::co_composed and std::variant?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, coroutine, asio

## Question

I want to treat `connection` classes that has same signature member functions. For example, both `tcp` and `tls` are kind of `connection` class. They have `send()` member function template that supports `CompletionToken`.
I use `std::variant` for `connection` type.

At some part of my application, I define `non_awaitable_func` function template. It supports `CompletionToken`, and I want to use `co_await` for its implementation. In this case, we can use [`asio::experimental::co_composed`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/cpp20_coroutines.html#boost_asio.overview.composition.cpp20_coroutines.lightweight_coroutines_implementing_asynchonous_operations).

So far, so good.

However, when I call `connection`'s `send()` member function template with `boost::asio::deferred` using `std::visit`, assertion failed happned.
It is because `std::visit` visitor functions' return type is different. `boost::asio::deferred` could create different return type that can be converted to the given signature.
Typically, in this case, I use `boost::asio::use_awaitable` instead of `boost::asio::deferred`. `boost::asio::use_awaitable` creates the same return type. However, in the `co_composed` implementation, I can't use `boost::asio::use_awaitable`.

Is there any good way to solve this situation?

### Demonstration code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/co_composed.hpp>

struct tcp {
    template <typename CompletionToken> // // void(boost::system::error_code)
    auto send(CompletionToken&& token) {
        // pseudo implementation
        auto tim = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(exe_, std::chrono::seconds(1));
        return tim->async_wait(
            boost::asio::consign(
                std::forward<CompletionToken>(token),
                tim
            )
        );
    }
    boost::asio::any_io_executor exe_;
};

struct tls {
    template <typename CompletionToken> // void(boost::system::error_code)
    auto send(CompletionToken&& token) {
        // pseudo implementation
        return boost::asio::dispatch(
            boost::asio::append(
                std::forward<CompletionToken>(token),
                boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message)
            )
        );
    }
    boost::asio::any_io_executor exe_;
};

#if 0 // if set 0 then no error happens because all visit return types are the same
using connection = std::variant<tcp, tls>;
#else
using connection = std::variant<tcp>;
#endif

template <typename CompletionToken>
auto non_awaitable_func(
    connection& con,
    CompletionToken&& token
) {
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<
        CompletionToken,
        void(boost::system::error_code)
    >(
        boost::asio::experimental::co_composed<
            void(boost::system::error_code)
        >(
            [](auto /*state*/, connection& con) -> void {
                auto [ec] = co_await std::visit(
                    [](auto& c) {
                        // use_awaitable can't be used here because of co_composed
                        return c.send(boost::asio::as_tuple(boost::asio::deferred));
                    },
                    con
                );
                // user defined implementation
                co_return {ec};
            }
        ),
        token,
        con
    );
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    connection con = tcp{ioc.get_executor()};
    non_awaitable_func(
        con,
        [&] (boost::system::error_code ec) {
            std::cout << "cb called:" << ec << std::endl;
        }
    );
    ioc.run();
}
```

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/b7zac6Pn1

### My workaround

I replaced `std::visit` with `std::get_if`.

```cpp
        boost::asio::experimental::co_composed<
            void(boost::system::error_code)
        >(
            [](auto /*state*/, connection& con) -> void {
                // No std::visit approach
                // However, not elegant and appears similar code repeatedly...
                if (auto* p = std::get_if<0>(&con)) {
                    auto [ec] = co_await p->send(boost::asio::as_tuple(boost::asio::deferred));
                    // user defined implementation
                    co_return {ec};
                }
                else {
                    // p conflicts
                    auto* q  = std::get_if<1>(&con);
                    BOOST_ASSERT(q);
                    auto [ec] = co_await q->send(boost::asio::as_tuple(boost::asio::deferred));
                    // user defined implementation
                    co_return {ec};
                }
            }
        ),
```

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/z8YMfMvMv

It works as I expected, but not elegant. I tried to use preprocessor macro to avoid code repeatation but I couldn't find a good way, so far.

## Environment

- Boost 1.84.0
- clang++ 17.0.1
- compiler option -std=c++20

## UPDATE

I noticed that the name of `non_awaitable_func()` is misleading. Let me clarify the meaning. I mean async function that doesn't have `boost::asio::awaitable<T>` return type. The async function has `CompletionToken` parameter. The parameter could be a callback function or any `CompletionToken` types that supports Boost.Asio. For example, `use_future`, `use_awaitable`, and `deferred`.

Comment: I implemented my workaround using boost preprocessor.  It can avoid code repeatation but still not elegant enough... https://godbolt.org/z/Y4P5YE51v

Comment: A little better macro based approach. https://godbolt.org/z/YhssvvWra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to type-erase the deferred async operations. Or write out the entire composed operation so the internal type discrepancies don't leak out to `co_composed`.

Both aren't without overhead, so perhaps you might flip the visitation inside out so the composed operation is never variant to begin with:

```
template <typename Connection, typename CompletionToken> auto non_awaitable_func_impl(Connection& con, CompletionToken&& token) {
    return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, Sig>(
        asio::experimental::co_composed<Sig>([](auto state, Connection& con) -> void {
            auto [ec] = co_await con.send(as_tuple(asio::deferred));
            co_yield state.complete(ec);
        }),
        token, con);
}

template <typename CompletionToken> auto non_awaitable_func(connection& con, CompletionToken&& token) {
    std::visit(
        [&token](auto& con) { return non_awaitable_func_impl(con, std::forward<CompletionToken>(token)); },
        con);
}
```

This works. You can combine the two if you don't mind readability:

```
template <typename CompletionToken> auto non_awaitable_func(connection& con, CompletionToken&& token) {
    return std::visit(
        [&token](auto& con) {
            return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, Sig>(
                asio::experimental::co_composed<Sig>([&con](auto state) -> void {
                    auto [ec] = co_await con.send(as_tuple(asio::deferred));
                    co_yield state.complete(ec);
                }),
                token);
        },
        con);
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12346f9a8a2cc25f)** (or [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tx5vvcM63))

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/co_composed.hpp>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio   = boost::asio;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
using Sig        = void(error_code);

struct tcp {
    template <asio::completion_token_for<Sig> Token> auto send(Token&& token) {
        // pseudo implementation
        auto tim = std::make_unique<asio::steady_timer>(exe_, 1s);
        return tim->async_wait(consign(std::forward<Token>(token), std::move(tim)));
    }
    asio::any_io_executor exe_;
};

struct tls {
    template <asio::completion_token_for<Sig> Token> auto send(Token&& token) {
        return dispatch( // pseudo implementation
            append(std::forward<Token>(token), make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message)));
    }
    asio::any_io_executor exe_;
};

using connection = std::variant<tcp, tls>;

template <asio::completion_token_for<Sig> Token> auto non_awaitable_func(connection& con, Token&& token) {
    return std::visit(
        [&token](auto& con) {
            return asio::async_initiate<Token, Sig>(
                asio::experimental::co_composed<Sig>([&con](auto state) -> void {
                    auto [ec] = co_await con.send(as_tuple(asio::deferred));
                    co_return state.complete(ec);
                }),
                token);
        },
        con);
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    connection 
        con1 = tls{ioc.get_executor()},
        con2 = tcp{ioc.get_executor()};

    non_awaitable_func(con1, [&](error_code ec) { std::cout << "cb1:" << ec.message() << std::endl; });
    non_awaitable_func(con2, [&](error_code ec) { std::cout << "cb2:" << ec.message() << std::endl; });
    ioc.run();
}
```

Note that it is important to let ADL find the correct `make_error_code` overload.

Prints:

```
cb1:Bad message
cb2:Success
```

### UPDATE: Promise!

I had a brainwave. Another experimental type, `asio::experimental::promise<>` which, like `std::promise`, apparently does some type erasure internally, yet, unlike `std::future` also can be `await`-transformed in Asio coroutines.

And indeed it works:

```
template <asio::completion_token_for<Sig> Token> //
auto async_send(connection& con, Token&& token) {
    return asio::async_initiate<Token, Sig>(
        boost::asio::experimental::co_composed<Sig>([&con](auto /*state*/) -> void {
            auto [ec] = co_await std::visit(
                [](auto& c) { return c.send(asio::as_tuple(asio::experimental::use_promise)); }, con);
            co_return {ec};
        }),
        token);
}
```

Here's a way more complete test program:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d0be2c3d4ba00d1)** or [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ofo189Kxz)

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/co_composed.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/promise.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/use_coro.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/use_promise.hpp>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio   = boost::asio;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
using Sig        = void(error_code);

static inline auto out() { return std::osyncstream(std::clog); }

struct tcp {
    template <asio::completion_token_for<Sig> Token> //
    auto send(Token&& token) {
        // pseudo implementation
        auto tim = std::make_unique<asio::steady_timer>(exe_, 1s);
        return tim->async_wait(consign(std::forward<Token>(token), std::move(tim)));
    }
    asio::any_io_executor exe_;
};

struct tls {
    template <asio::completion_token_for<Sig> Token> //
    auto send(Token&& token) {
        return dispatch( // pseudo implementation
            append(std::forward<Token>(token), make_error_code(boost::system::errc::bad_message)));
    }
    asio::any_io_executor exe_;
};

using connection = std::variant<tcp, tls>;

template <asio::completion_token_for<Sig> Token> //
auto async_send(connection& con, Token&& token) {
    return asio::async_initiate<Token, Sig>(
        boost::asio::experimental::co_composed<Sig>([&con](auto /*state*/) -> void {
            auto [ec] = co_await std::visit(
                [](auto& c) { return c.send(asio::as_tuple(asio::experimental::use_promise)); }, con);
            co_return {ec};
        }),
        token);
}

template <class V> // HT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697591/85371
std::type_info const& var_type(V const& v) {
    return std::visit([](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) { return typeid(x); }, v);
}

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool ioc(1);

    connection 
        con1 = tls{ioc.get_executor()},
        con2 = tcp{ioc.get_executor()};

    { // callback
        async_send(con1, [&](error_code ec) { out() << "cb1:" << ec.message() << std::endl; });
        async_send(con2, [&](error_code ec) { out() << "cb2:" << ec.message() << std::endl; });
    }

    { // use_future
        auto f1 = async_send(con1, as_tuple(asio::use_future));
        auto f2 = async_send(con2, as_tuple(asio::use_future));
        out() << "f1: " << std::get<0>(f1.get()).message() << std::endl;
        out() << "f2: " << std::get<0>(f2.get()).message() << std::endl;

        try {
            async_send(con1, asio::use_future).get();
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
            out() << "alternatively: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    { // use_awaitable
        for (connection& con : {std::ref(con1), std::ref(con2)}) {
            auto name = "coro-" + boost::core::demangle(var_type(con).name());
            co_spawn(
                ioc,
                [&con, name]() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
                    auto [ec_defer] = co_await async_send(con, as_tuple(asio::deferred));
                    auto [ec_aw]    = co_await async_send(con, as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable));
                    out() << name << ": " << ec_defer.message() << "/" << ec_aw.message() << std::endl;
                    co_await async_send(con, asio::deferred); // will throw
                },
                [name](std::exception_ptr e) {
                    try {
                        if (e)
                            std::rethrow_exception(e);
                    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
                        out() << name << " threw " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    ioc.join();
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
cb1:Bad message
f1: Bad message
cb2:Success
f2: Success
alternatively: Bad message
coro-tls: Bad message/Bad message
coro-tls threw Bad message
coro-tcp: Success/Success
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I use your non_awaitable_func with deferred, then `static_assert(__visit_rettypes_match,` still failed on outer `visit()`. See https://godbolt.org/z/7onWKK8v1 (modified from your godbolt link)

Comment: I noticed that the name of non_awaitable_func() could mislead you. non_awaitable_func() means an async function that doesn't have `awaitable<T>` return type. However, the function can use with any CompletionToken. For example, callbacks, use_future, use_awaitabe, deferred ...
That is my intention.

Comment: In that case, you still have the type erasure thing. Indeed the name mislead me, because e.g. callbacks and use_future are fine: https://godbolt.org/z/v63656Eqc. Shame because I already spent way too much time. I'll see if I can revisit later

Comment: Good news. I had a brainwave and it panned out: see Update (or https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d0be2c3d4ba00d1)

Comment: What a great solution! I really respect your effort. I applied use_promise to my actual project code and it works perfectly. In addition, I've checked the performance on my environment. The reesult　was  `use_promise`, `deferred`, and `use_awaitable`  in descending order of the performance. It's nice!
Thank you very much!

Comment: I got some interesting results: https://godbolt.org/z/xePvsxW8E
When I call async function with use_promise, basic_system_executor is used by default after co_await. If I want to enforce the specific executor, I need to pass the executor as 2nd argument of co_composed. When I use dererred instead of use_promise, the current executor is used continuously. As the result of that, the 2nd argument of co_composed seems to be ignored.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that may be by design. You invoke the outer operation with a callback ***without*** associated executor (the lambda is neutral). It doesn't matter in any way that the invocation happens "on a strand": what matters is the bound executor. This is why all the asio IO objects have their own bound executor (which you can rebind) and all the free functions deduce one from the IO object argument(s) involved. `async_compose` and `co_composed` both take these executors/IO objects as arguments.

Comment: This is how I'd design the interface https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/380ea16793d27a74. Perhaps I should not suggest the alternative because it violates "Pit Of Success" design guideline, but it would look like this: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f15a4bda8c0e6f24 - try that if you like to field 10 support calls about system_executor being used every month :) In unrelated news, I think `system_executor` may have been a mistake. I bet it's one of these things mediated by the ISO committee workgroup back when... :|

Comment: In truly unrelated news, I ran into several of your SML answers, and I'm very humbled. You really show some expert knowlegde combined with awesome code-style!

Comment: Indeed, the last bound executor is used after co_await. It sometimes go against (my) instinct. Even if I set `co_await async_func(..., bind_executor(exe, deferred))`, exe might not be a current executor because other executor could be bound in async_func implementation.
Maybe I should insert `co_await dispatch(bind_executor(expected_exe, deferred))` after every co_await call if I expect a specific executor. Maybe it is a good practice.

Comment: It's often against my intuition as well. I think the core confusion comes from your intuition about "current executor", which in the Asio model isn't really a thing. It makes sense for our brains, but that's it. For asio the only thing that matters is "where do I run the next handler" :)
And yes, that advice echoes what I've landed on before (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77783929/85371). It may usually be a code smell when you have to force-resume a coro on a specific strand. Coro's are best viewed as their own logical strand (for free!) guarding the variables in its stack frame