# C++ type loophole explanation

Tags: c++, c++14

The silly question. Could anyone please explain to me how this code works? (from here https://alexpolt.github.io/type-loophole.html)

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<int N> struct tag{};

template<typename T, int N>
struct loophole_t {
  friend auto loophole(tag<N>) { return T{}; };
};

auto loophole(tag<0>);

int main() {

sizeof( loophole_t<std::string, 0> );
    
static_assert(std::is_same< std::string, decltype( loophole(tag<0>{}) ) >::value);

}
```

It looks like `sizeof( loophole_t<std::string, 0> );` affects compiler global state. I mean if we remove this line `static_asserts` fails. Is at allowed for C++?

UPDATE:
Just realized it depends on compiler or even compiler version.
Works pretty well with any GCC >=8 (probably with older versions as well).
Does not compile with clang >= 10, but works fine with clang 7.0

So I'd say my real question whether it is a compiler bug or a standard behavior?

Comment: What compiler are you using, that produces such (unexpected) behavior? Did all C++ compilers, that you tested, produced the same output, or just that one?

Comment: Oh yeah, it actually depends on compiler. works with GCC, fails to compile with clang.

Comment: @Dmitry [Works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f98cda3bbc7bf585)

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings
Hmm... Looks like depends on compiler version. You can try here with clang 11 https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @Dmitry Because you tried to "save" two types with the same tag. I'm sure that's by design.

Comment: You can comment the second "store", I just forgot to remove it

Comment: [There _is_ a problem, though](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/no4Yr6)

Comment: That's actually interesting, and relates to how friends are scoped when first declared inside a class definition. I wonder whether Clang is right about this.

Comment: [Here's a testcase for that](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5aKWTx). Smells like a Clang bug to me.

Comment: [Further evidence of general clang `friend` buginess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50194159/4386278)

Comment: That's just a link to the front page, not to a snippet

Comment: Oh, yeah, this is the one https://godbolt.org/z/Os2oGo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It causes instantiation of the template specialisation `loophole_t<std::string, 0>`.

As a class template with a `friend` function (and remember, `friend`s aren't members), that [also brings the function into scope](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-3.1) in the global namespace.

That function could be spelt `std::string loophole(tag<0> unusedParam);`.

It's not directly used for anything other than a throw-away `sizeof` after that, except to "retrieve" its return type with `decltype` and compare it to `std::string` in a static assertion (which is expected to pass, by way of demonstration).

The author has "stored" `std::string` in the expression `tag<0>`. Sort of.

If you wrote more of them:

```
sizeof( loophole_t<std::string, 0> );
sizeof( loophole_t<int, 1> );
sizeof( loophole_t<char, 2> );
```

… you'd end up with a whole bunch of functions in scope, which could be spelt:

```
std::string loophole(tag<0> unusedParam);
int loophole(tag<1> unusedParam);
char loophole(tag<2> unusedParam);
```

… and now you can see that the function declarations "store" a type for each tag. We can "access" the types using the tags:

```
decltype(loophole(tag<0>{})) thisIsAString = "lol";
decltype(loophole(tag<1>{})) thisIsAnInt = 42;
decltype(loophole(tag<2>{})) thisIsAChar = '!';
```

Of what actual benefit this is, I do not know. But if you're desperate for it, you could just:

```
using MyTypes = std::tuple<std::string, int, char>;
```

… then use [somewhat more idiomatic means to extract type *N*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16928694/4386278).

Comment: Re: "what actual benefit": reflection. For ex. to get a type of a member of a structure. Otherwise, how you'd do this?